# UILabel is not updated with UITableViewCell custom class Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uilabel

I am very new at Swift programming so don't judge me strong. I've spent a lot of time trying to understand where the problem is, but I cannot get it.

I have a UITableView inside of a UIViewController

**UIViewController:**

```
@IBOutlet weak var myTableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    myTableView.delegate = self
    myTableView.dataSource = self
}



func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return 10
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyTableViewCell

    cell.createNewCell()
    return cell
}
```

In my custom UITableViewCell class I have `myLabel` - label that I've attached in storyboard.

```
@IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!
  func createNewCell(){
        myLabel.text = "1234567"
    }
```

But if I add the following line `cell.textLabel!.text = "12312"` to `cellForRowAtIndexPath` when my cells update, the cell does not update when I am trying to update them through the custom UITableViewCell class.

Comment: I edited your question, still it is unclear what you are asking. Your last 2 sentences are not clear

Answer (score 2):

I think you should do this way:

1) Create your custom cell

```
class customCell: UITableViewCell
{
    @IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!
}
```

2) Set an identifier for reusable cell and in cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! customCell
    cell.myLabel.text = "1234"
    return cell
```

Comment: No, as you can see MyTableViewCell was already created like that

Answer (score 0):

You have to reload the tablewView if you are updating the data in cell.
If your datasource array is updated and you want to populate updated data in tableview then just reloadtableview.

```
    @IBOutlet weak var myTableView: UITableView!
    var dataSource= [String]()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
     myTableView.delegate = self
     myTableView.dataSource = self
     dataSource = ["item1", "item2", "item3"]
   }

   func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
   }

   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return dataSource.count
  }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
      let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyTableViewCell

      cell.myLabel.text = dataSource[indexPath.row]
      return cell
  }
     //Suppose in some function you changed the datasource
    func updateData() {
      dataSource = ["number1", "number2", "number3"]
     //Now just call 
     myTableView.reloadData() 

}
```

Comment: no, the problem is that initial data is not shown, I do not need to reloadData() to show the initial data

Answer (score 0):

I found where the problem was. Actually my UITableView was inside of UIViewController that was inside of tabBarController. That is why constraints were not applied on runtime in Xcode 7.3.1.

I fixed it with setting **installed checkbox** to true for all the constraints and for UILabel in the cell.